# How to filter a time-series given a threshold and buffer time between in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to filter two different years within a time-series given a threshold. For the first year, I want to grab the first instance of when the value crossed the threshold. However, if that value is past that threshold in consecutive years, I want to grab the date with the last time that consecutive value occurs. Secondly, within that time-series, I want to grab the second instance that threshold is crossed. However, this time in cannot come within two-years of the first selected value and if it does to not use that value. An example of how this might look is:

```
dat <- data.frame(time = as.Date(c("2001-12-31","2002-12-31","2003-12-31","2004-12-31", 
                                   "2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2008-12-31")),
                  value = c(-52.1,-52.44,23.5,-64.2,10.7,-15.4,-52.4,231.7))
```

I want to filter those values with value <= -50 and select the two years given the criteria. The expected output would be:

```
2002-12-31
2007-12-31
```

I tried following a similar framework with using the slice function to grab the dates (from another question: [Choosing first instance of a value by year in a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278233/choosing-first-instance-of-a-value-by-year-in-a-time-series)), but was not sure how to follow the extraction of the criteria for different thresholds. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi! This part was a little unclear to me, but I hope I got it right: "this time in cannot come within two-years of the first selected value and if it does to not use that value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a combination of run-length encoding (one of `base::rle`, `dplyr::consecutive_id`, or `data.table::rleid`) and some simpler filtering.

You'll see the use of `2*365+2` as a discriminator: the `POSIXt`-methods for time-differencing do not have `"year"` as an option, so we need to go with days, and there's a leap-year in 2002-2007.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(value <= -50)) %>%
  filter(any(value <= -50), row_number() == n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1L | difftime(time, time[1], units="day") >= (2*365+2))
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   time       value   grp
#   <date>     <dbl> <int>
# 1 2002-12-31 -52.4     1
# 2 2007-12-31 -52.4     5
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[any(value <= -50), .(time, value)][.N,], by = .(grp = rleid(value <= -50))
  ][(seq(.N) == 1 | difftime(time, time[1], units="day") >= (2*365+2)),]
#      grp       time  value
#    <int>     <Date>  <num>
# 1:     1 2002-12-31 -52.44
# 2:     5 2007-12-31 -52.40
```

## base R

(A little more work.)

```r
# a home-grown base-R version of `rleid` and `consecutive_id` above
my_rleid <- function(...) {
  r <- rle(do.call(paste, c(list(...), sep = "_")))$lengths
  rep(seq_along(r), times = r)
}
dat |>
  transform(grp = my_rleid(value <= -50)) |>
  subset(ave(value <= -50, grp, FUN = function(z) any(z) & seq_along(z) == length(z))) |>
  subset(seq_along(time) == 1L | difftime(time, time[1], units="day") >= (2*365+2))
#         time  value grp
# 2 2002-12-31 -52.44   1
# 7 2007-12-31 -52.40   5
```

Answer (score 1):

First we create the filtering conditions as columns, to make everything more readable and easier to adjust afterwards:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat |> 
  mutate(threshold  = ifelse(value <= -50, "yes", "no")) |> 
  mutate(year = year(time),
         previous_year = year(lag(time))) |> 
  mutate(consecutive = case_when(threshold == "yes" & previous_year == year-1 ~ "yes", 
                                 .default = "no"))
```

Then we filter according to the first conditions:

```
dat3 <- dat2 |> 
  filter(threshold == "yes") |> 
  filter(consecutive == "yes")
```

We create again the `previous_year` variable, and the second condition:

```
dat4 <- dat3 |> 
  mutate(previous_year = year(lag(time))) |>
  mutate(within_two = ifelse(previous_year+2 >= year, "yes", "no"))
```

Finally, we filter according to the second condition, and we get your desired output:

```
dat5 |> 
  filter(within_two != "yes" | is.na(within_two))
```

Output:

```
#        time  value threshold year previous_year consecutive within_two
#1 2002-12-31 -52.44       yes 2002            NA         yes       <NA>
#2 2007-12-31 -52.40       yes 2007          2004         yes         no
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output by using `shift` to put the previous date on the row with a `value >= -50` and then filtering to get the `min` and `max` dates from the `time` column

```
dat <- data.frame(time = as.Date(c("2001-12-31","2002-12-31","2003-12-31","2004-12-31", 
                                 "2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2008-12-31")),
                value = c(-52.1,-52.44,23.5,-64.2,10.7,-15.4,-52.4,231.7))

library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
    mutate( time2 = ifelse(value >= -50,shift(time),NA) ) %>%
    mutate( time2 = as.Date(time2) ) %>% 
    filter(time == min(time2,na.rm=T) | time == max(time2,na.rm=T))
```